# How to list all files of a directory and its subdirectories in php?

Tags: php, file

How can I find all the file names of a directory or folder and its sub-directories or sub-folders.
I am using `scandir()`, but It returns files and sub-directory names both only from root directory.
If anybody have a solution then please suggest.

```
<?php
    $dir    = 'mydir/';
    $files  = scandir($dir);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. 
I have created a script, by using this we can get or list all the files of a directory and its sub-directories. 
Its working fine.In there mydir assumed as the directory path

```
function listDirFiles($dir){
    foreach(glob("$dir/*") as $ff){          
            is_dir($ff) ? listDirFiles($ff) : $GLOBALS['a'][] = basename($ff);        
    }
}

listDirFiles('mydir');
echo "<pre>", print_r($GLOBALS['a']), "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $filelist = array();
  if ($handle = opendir(".")) 
  {
    while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
        if (is_file($entry)) {
            $filelist[] = $entry;
        }
    }
  echo "<pre>";
print_r($filelist);
closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: It is also listing subdirectories name. I just want only file names.

Comment: @AmitRajput i have updated the answer

Comment: It is also not working properly. Its listing only .php files.

Comment: @AmitRajput i have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#110570) can give you more light.

What I would do (like in the answer) is run a foreach loop for each directory and then list the files in directories in that. Basically just rinse and repeat. PHP does the `scandir()` function similar to the `ls` command in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my project, this will only return file but not folder and it's recursively.

```
$dir = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("mydir/") );
$dir->setFlags(4096 | 8192);

foreach ($dir as $value) {
    echo $dir->getSubPathname();
}
```